# How to save or assign information to a button? Ant Design React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, button, antd

I need to be able to assign or save within each button each dictionary with the set of checkboxes (if it is active or not, true/false)

My view is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOXMh.png)

I need each button to save the selected checkboxes next to it so that I can submit them in a form to that information.

My code is something like this:

```
 <Form.Item>
   Object.entries(data?.permissions_grid)
   .map(([key, value]) => (
      <Button
        onClick={() => { props.buttonSelection(value.permissions_template)} }>
        {value.name} 
      </Button>
    ))
 </Form.Item>

 <Form.Item>
   !_.isEmpty(dataPermissions) &&
     Object.entries(dataPermissions)
       .map(([key, value]) => (
           <Row className="check-permissions">
              <Checkbox
                onChange={onChange}>
                {key}
              </Checkbox>
            </Row>
        ))
 </Form.Item>
```

This information comes to me from the back, they are two objects that I am going through. The back waits for the next response:

```
"name": "Consultor 3",
   "description": "",
   "edit_permissions_grid": {
       "1": {
           "name": "Audios Textos",
           "description": "Listado de audios con filtros",
           "url": "/audios",
           "selected_permissions": {
               "add": true,
               "delete": false,
               "edit": false,
               "query": true,
               "download": false,
               "play": false
           }
       },
       "2": {
           "name": "Reportes",
           "description": "reportes",
           "url": "/reportes",
           "selected_permissions": {
               "add": false,
               "delete": false,
               "edit": false,
               "query": false,
               "download": true,
               "play": false
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's render those checkboxs inside a `<Checkbox.Group />` and use values `string[]` to control the checked item(s).

antd checkbox: https://ant.design/components/checkbox/

Comment: Using this?: `<Checkbox.Group>
  <Checkbox value="A">A</Checkbox>
  <Checkbox value="B">B</Checkbox>
</Checkbox.Group>`. How do I assign this information to each Button?

Comment: const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];

<Checkbox.Group  option={plainOptions} value={['Apple']} onChange={onChange} />

Comment: the value array will control which checkbox is ticked, in order.